# Android Frameworks/Technologies to improve development

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee

I am planing my new Android project and I would like to know which frameworks/technologies you can recommend.
Currently I want to use:

- roboguice
- greenDAO

Anybody another good tools to improve Android development?

Thanks for help!

Regards,

Markus

Answer (score 0):

If this is your first project, don't use any frameworks. This will let you learn how the core platform works, without potentially confusing layers on top of it. Once you are fairly comfortable writing (and reading!) Android code, by all means add frameworks to get more productive.

As for the actual frameworks, what part of development do you want to make more productive/easy, etc? If you can't answer this question right now, see above.

Answer (score 0):

For UI, [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) is pretty handy.
If you are using databases, you might look at [ORMlite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml).